# JS Text Parser Not Working

Tags: javascript

I wanted to make a text parser of sorts and I have done lots of research.

I was wondering if I am using javascript correctly. I know you shouldnt really make text parsers in js but it is the only scripting language of which I know.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script>
  function makeCode() {
    for (i = 0; i < userCode.length; i++) {
    if (userCode.substring("print:"(0, 6)) {
      document.write(usercode.substring("print:"(6,0));
  }
</script>

<style>
  p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #cc0000;
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Impact;
    color: #cc0000;
  }
  body { 
    text-align: center;
  }
  form {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<h1>NCPL</h1>
<p style="font-size: 10px">In Browser NinjaCorp Programming Language Editor</p>
</head>
<body>
<form name="userCode">
    <textarea id="userCode" name="userCode" cols="80" rows="20" placeholder="Type your code     here"></textarea></br>
    <a href="javascript:makeCode()"><button type="button">Run Code!</button></a>
</form>
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: dont use document.write() it can be a form of eval.

Comment: ``userCode`` is undefined inside your function. You have to fetch it from the DOM first, something like ``var userCode = document.getElementById('userCode').value`` or so. Further, your use of substring is meaningless. What's with the fixed string "print" in there? What is supposed to happen when the user clicks the button?

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what you're looking for?**

```js
function makeBode() {
    var userCode = document.getElementById('userCode').value;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  
     // alert(userCode)
    for (i = 0; i < userCode.length; i++) {
       myDiv.innerHTML =  myDiv.innerHTML  + userCode.substring((i,i+6)) +'<br>'; 
    }

}
```

```css
p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #cc0000;
  }
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Impact;
    color: #cc0000;
  }
  body { 
    text-align: center;
  }
  form {
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<h1>NCPL</h1>
<p style="font-size: 10px">In Browser NinjaCorp Programming Language Editor</p>
</head>
<body>
  
<form name="userCode">
    <textarea id="userCode" name="userCode" cols="80" rows="20" placeholder="Type your code     here">Typing here so there is some text to work with </textarea></br>
    <a href="javascript:makeBode();"><button type="button">Run Code!</button></a>
  
</form>
```

Comment: No, I was looking for something that makes it not say print and say the text after it. Thanks anyway